# Setting TextView TextAppeareance Programmatically in android

Tags: android, textview

I am going to implement a `LinearLayout` in which the input fields are programmatically generated according to the number of fields of the database table.

Unfortunately, when I am trying to set the attribute: `textApperance` as `textApperanceLarge` in the `TextView`, it doesn't work. Below is my code...

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedProducts; i++) {

            premLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
            premLayout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            premLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            premLayout[i].setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

            premTextView[i] = new TextView(this);
            premTextView[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    2.0f));
            premTextView[i].setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);

            premTextView[i].setText(premiumChannels.get(i));
            premTextView[i].setId(i + 600);

            int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            premTextView[i].setWidth(px);

            premLayout[i].addView(premTextView[i]);
```

Comment: By not working, I assume you mean the text is just "normal sized"?

Comment: the default size is TextAppearanceSmall...but I want to to set...TextAppearanceLarge.

Comment: you are building your own text appearance attribute or you are using from android. in your code you are using from android .

Comment: I am trying to use   text appearance provided by android.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Use like this. It will work.

```
textView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

Or, since API 23, you don't need to pass a context. Hence, you can simply call:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
```

If you want to support API 23 or higher as well as lower one, you can use the below method to simplify your task. Use the below method only if you are already targeting API 23 or higher. If you are targeting API is less than 23, the below code will give error as the new method wasn't available in it.

```
public void setTextAppearance(Context context, int resId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        super.setTextAppearance(context, resId);
    } else {
        super.setTextAppearance(resId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works !
when shall we use
android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge instead of android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati: `android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge` is an attribute that sets the style to use for the current theme. You can give it any value when you use a custom theme. `android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large` is a style, and in this case it happens to be the value set to the attr, for the default theme.

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use setTextAppearance(int) instead in API 23+.

Comment: I get the following error on the lines with super.setTextAppea...
"Cannot resolve method setTextAppearance(int)"
Of course another solution would be not to monkeypatch setTextAppearance but it would be nice to get this working

Comment: Use `setTextAppearance(@NonNull TextView textView, @StyleRes int resId)` for downward compatibility.

Comment: @Arst mean `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(@NonNull TextView textView, @StyleRes int resId)`

Answer (score 36):

Use `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance()` method which will take care of your sdk version checks.

Comment: How do you use this?  I have the View.

Comment: @doctorram this is only for textview. If your view is textview then just use this method - TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(your_text_view_here, R.style.yourStyle_which_want_to_apply);

Comment: This is simpler than accepted answer