# No such method error while setting text appearance

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using the following code to change the font size to medium or high or small. `getFontSize()` will return any of these sizes

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
     holder.title.setTextAppearance(new AppController().getFontSize());
 else
     holder.title.setTextAppearance(mContext, new AppController().getFontSize());
```

But im getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTextAppearance(I)V in class Landroid/widget/TextView; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.widget.TextView' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
```

Why am I getting such error?

Comment: see the issue here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183542

Comment: It looks like the compiler should fail but It doesn't so it crashes in live.
According to @rafsanahmad007 link I think it is related to a @ deprecated method.

Comment: Are you sure `new AppController().getFontSize()` returns `@StyleRes int` (`int` representing a style resource)?

Comment: Try to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270814/setting-textview-textappeareance-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextView::setTextAppearance` expects an integer value, that identifies a style resource in the project (like `@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Body1`).
If this is your intention, then make sure, that your getFontSize() method returns a valid ID.

But, I guess, that you a actually trying to set the font size, which should be done using the `setTextSize(float size)` method of TextView.

Comment: But I am setting style in   chip.setTextAppearance(R.style.ChipTextStyle_Selected);

Comment: where style is 
    <style name="ChipTextStyle_Selected" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/chip_color_selector</item>
    </style>

Comment: Any update on this? I am also setting the style to Chip and it's crashing in few Lollipop Devices. @AndroidGeek